# Difference between car 損保 and 車両保険

Tags: words, meaning

A person asked for car insurance recommendations, and here is the whole reply of another person:

> うちは以前ソニー損保つ使ってたね。何回か事故ったりしてたけど特に不満はなかったかな、値段も安かったし。車両保険はつけたことがないのでよくわからないんだけど。

I am confused: Isn't ソニー損保 a kind of 車両保険?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the 損保 in the reply is only the most basic insurance option (covering damage caused to others).

車両保険 on the other side covers self-accidents, accidents caused by oneself, and natural damages.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ソニー損保 is a name of an insurance company. 車両保険 is one of car insurance options.